# Python How to modify Y value in a list of X,Y points for lines

Tags: python

I am using python (2.7) and I have a long nested list of X,Y coordinates specifying end points of lines. I need to shift the Y coordinates by a specified amount. For instance, this is what I would like to do:

```
lines = [((2, 98), (66, 32)), ((67, 31), (96, 2)), ((40, 52), (88, 3))]
```

perform some coding that is eluding me to get...

```
lines = [((2, 198), (66, 132)), ((67, 131), (96, 102)), ((40, 152), (88, 103))
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can go about accomplishing this? Thank you for the help!!

Comment: So you want to add 100 to the second element of each tuple?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus That doesn't really help.  And besides a new tuple can be created in each element of the list with the modifications.

Comment: @SethMMorton Sorry, meant to be a joke, but realized it's not a very good one. Deleting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
>>> dy = 100
>>> lines = [((2, 98), (66, 32)), ((67, 31), (96, 2)), ((40, 52), (88, 3))]
>>> newlines = [tuple((x,y+dy) for x,y in subline) for subline in lines]
>>> newlines
[((2, 198), (66, 132)), ((67, 131), (96, 102)), ((40, 152), (88, 103))]
```

which is roughly the same as:

```
newlines = []
for subline in lines:
    tmp = []
    for x,y in subline:
        tmp.append((x, y+dy))
    tmp = tuple(tmp)
    newlines.append(tmp)
```

Comment: This worked great for what I needed to do. Thank you again DSM!

Answer (score 2):

In programming, divide things into smaller units.

Define a function that shifts one point:

```
def shift_point(point, dx=0, dy=0):
    x, y = point
    return (x + dx, y + dy)
```

Then one that shifts a line:

```
def shift_line(line, dx=0, dy=0):
    point1, point2 = line
    return (shift_point(point1, dx, dy),
            shift_point(point2, dx, dy))
```

Finally, create the new list using a list comprehension:

```
lines = [((2, 98), (66, 32)), ((67, 31), (96, 2)), ((40, 52), (88, 3))]
lines = [shift_line(line, dy=100) for line in lines]
```

Will give the result you need. There are much shorter solutions, but doing it like this builds good habits, I think.

(edit: changed variable names 'xdistance' and 'ydistance' into 'dx' and 'dy')

Comment: This is also a useful method for what I am trying to accomplish. Works great. Thank you RemcoGerlich!

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, so as currently structured it's impossible without making either the line or the point a list, or rebuilding from scratch each time

point as a list, line as a tuple:

```
line = lines[0]
for point in line:
    point[1] += 100
```

line as a list, point as a tuple:

```
line = lines[0]
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(line):
    line[i] = x, y+100
```

or rebuilding the object entirely:

```
lines[0] = tuple(((x, y+100) for x, y in lines[0]))
```